# Function not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

When I run the following code with sql stored procedure I get the -1 instead of the correct result. What is wrong with the code? Please help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetTopMaterial 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP (1) MaterialId
FROM Materials
END


public static int GetTopMaterial()
{
   SqlHelper objSqlHelper = new SqlHelper();
   return (int)objSqlHelper.ExecuteScalar("GetTopMaterial");
}

 int id =Cart.GetTopMaterial()

public object ExecuteScalar (string query)
{
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection (strConnectionString);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (query, cnn);
 if (query.StartsWith ("SELECT") | query.StartsWith ("select"))
 {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 }
 else
 {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 }
 cnn.Open ();
 object retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
 cnn.Close ();
 return retval;
}

public object ExecuteScalar(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters) 
{
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
        if (query.StartsWith("SELECT") | query.StartsWith("select"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= parameters.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i]);
        }
        cnn.Open();
        object retval = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cnn.Close();
        return retval;
}
```

Comment: Place your code between a try/catch and show us the exception

Comment: I am not getting any error but the result is -1 instead of the actual value in the table.

Comment: And your transact code runs fine from SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Are you sure there's no row in Materials with MaterialId = -1?

Comment: What is the SqlHelper class? Is it maybe returning -1 to indicate something went wrong?

Comment: query running fine in sql management studio. there is no material with id -1. the top 1 is 4. sqlhelper is working fine with many other procedures and fucntions

Comment: Top (1) ordered by what? While not the source of your error, top is meaningless without order by. Also maybe the app doesn't have permissions, maybe you should specify the schema, and maybe you should ensure that you're looking at the same copy of the database (e.g. if the app is using `AttachDbFileName`).

Comment: I tried order by id but still same result . May be something wrong with executeScalar fucntion, I have posted the function in the code section.

Comment: What are you actually passing to this method? Is it calling a stored procedure or straight SQL? If the latter what is your SQL? Either way does it return -1 for all SQL/Stored procedures?

Comment: I've just noticed the revision history... you seem to be changing the question to invalidate answers. The answer below from ethorn10 seemed to answer the question but now you've changed the question so that it isn't a valid answer... You shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So your `ExecuteScalar` is actually wrapping an `ExecuteNonQuery`. From [MSDN for ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Comment: I have two ExecuteScalar functions there in the class. May be that is problme? I posted the code in the code section.

Comment: Am I missing something? I only see one ExecuteScalar function that you posted. If they're both wrapping an `ExecuteNonQuery`, it will always return a -1 for your stored procedure that is simply doing a `SELECT`.

Comment: Exactly this. The return value of the function is **NOT** the return value of your SQL function, and it's **NOT** the row returned by the query, it's only the number of affected rows: `ExecuteNonQuery: Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.`.

Comment: That's fine. But consider renaming your functions to accurately depict what they are doing. Calling a function `ExecuteScalar` when in reality it is performing an `ExecuteNonQuery` is going to lead to issues like this when debugging.

Comment: I posted the second function only now.